# White is missing

Tags: visual, pattern, flags

**All of the country flags below can be replaced by other flags. One country flag is missing and can *not* be replaced by another flag. Find the missing flag and explain why it's correct.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The missing flag is ...

> ... the flag of **Ivory Coast**:
>
>  [image: Ivory Coast]

All of the country flags below can be replaced by other flags.

> **Iceland** can be replaced by India, Israel or Italy, among others.
>  **Mexico** can only be replaced by Luxembourg.
>  **Finland** could be Chile, Italy again or the Philippines.
>  **Morocco** could also be France, Greece or Mexico, among others.
>  The **United States** could be Barbados, Bermuda, Poland or many more.
>  **Belgium** could be Suriname or Vietnam.

Let's have a closer look at the flag arrangement:

> **`I`** `C` `E` `L` `A` `N` `D`
>
>  `M` `E` **`X`** `I` `C` `O`
>  `F` `I` `N` **`L`** `A` `N` `D`
>  `M` `O` `R` `O` **`C`** `C` `O`
>  `U` `N` `I` `T` `E` **`D`**   `S` `T` `A` `T` `E` `S`
>  `B` `E` `L` `G` `I` `U` **`M`**

There's a pattern:

> When the names of the countries whose flags are shown are spelled out, the letters on the diagonal correspond to the roman numerals: I, V, X, L, C, D and M in ascending order of their values. In other words, the *n*-th letter of the name of the *n*-th country is the *n*-th Roman numeral.
>
>  So we're looking for a country whose second letter is a **V**. There's only one such country: **Ivory Coast**. (But only if you don't insist on calling it *Côte d'Ivoire*.)

The title:

> "White" could be an allusion to ivory as a shade of off-white.

Comment: This is the missing flag and you got the correct interpretation of the title too. Well done!

Comment: Great puzzle, @M Oehm. I guess it's yourself who has made it up, right?